# import urlresolvers from django.core in django 2 after upgrading from django 1

Tags: python, django, python-3.x

trying to import:

```
from django.core import urlresolvers
```

I get:

```
ImportError: cannot import name 'urlresolvers' from 'django.core'
```

This is because UrlResolvers are deprecated and replaced with Django.Url. However I am looking for the actual UrlResolvers in order to find:

```
urlresolvers.get_resolver(None)
```

I cant find where this method has gone in the documentation.

Using Latest django and Python 3.7 now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Django 2 changes the URLs, you can `from django.urls import path, get_resolver` etc.

From the django docs, to clarify the basic URL setup;

```
from django.urls import get_resolver

get_resolver(None)
```

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/http/urls/

The source is here for the resolvers; https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/_modules/django/urls/resolvers/

Answer (score 1):

`django.core.urlresolvers` no longer exists in Django 2.0.  Instead, you can find it in `django.urls`.